# What is the difference between non-linear oscillator and non-uniform oscillator?

Tags: terminology, definition, oscillators, non-linear-systems

The equation for a uniform oscillator is: $\dot\theta = \omega$ which has a solution of $\theta(t) = \omega t +\theta_0$.

For a non-uniform oscillator, the equation is: $\dot\theta= \omega - a$ where $a(\theta) \ne 0$.

These definitions are from Strogatz's book. Now I don't understand the difference between non-uniform and non-linear. Isn't a non-uniform oscillator is also a kind of non-linear oscillator? What is the difference between them?

Comment: $\dot \theta = \omega$ has the solution $\theta(t) = \omega t + \theta_0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a more fundamental level the difference is between a [*linear* differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation), *homogeneous differential equation*, and an equation with constant coefficients.

**Linear (ordinary) differential equation**
If we take an equation
$$\mathcal{L}x(t)=f(t),$$
where $\mathcal{L}$ is an arbitrary differential operator, then it is linear if the differential operator is linear, i.e., if for any functions $x(t),y(t)$ and any coefficients $a,b$, the action of the operator on the  linear combination of these functions, $z(t)=ax(t)+by(t)$ is just a linear combination of its action on each of the functions
$$\mathcal{L}z(t)=a\mathcal{L}x(t)+b\mathcal{L}y(t).$$

**Homogeneous differential equation**
Further, we can write a linear operator as
$$
\mathcal{L}=\sum_n a_n(t)\frac{d^n}{dt^n},$$
so that the corresponding linear equation can be written as
$$\sum_n a_n(t)\frac{d^n x(t)}{dt^n}=f(t).$$
If the right-hand-side of thsi equation is zero, i.e., if we have only the derivative terms, then the equation is called *homogeneous*, otherwise - *inhomogeneous*.

**Differential equation with constant coefficients**
Finally, if the coefficients of the equation, $\{a_n(t)\}$ are constant (i.e., independent on $t$), it is called an equation with constant coefficients.

**Oscillator**
Oscillator is generally described by differential equation
$$
\ddot{x}(t)+\omega_0^2x(t)=0\Leftrightarrow \mathcal{L}=\frac{d^2}{dt^2}+\omega_0^2, \mathcal{L}x(t)=f(t)$$
This is a homogeneous linear differential equation with constant coefficients. Adding a driving force makes it inhomogeneous. (Perhaps, this is what is meant by *non-uniform*, although it may also refer to *non-constant coefficients*.)

Answer (score 1):

Without referring to the source material, the differential equation $$\theta = \omega - a(\theta)$$ is linear if $a(\theta)$ is a linear relationship, i.e. $a(\theta) = k \theta$, with $k$ constant.  It's only nonlinear if $a(\theta)$ is a nonlinear relation.

Comment: So an oscillator can be non-uniform without being non-linear and vice-versa?

Comment: Btw, in the example of the book, they used $a(\theta)=a \sin \theta$. So, it seems that is non-uniform and also non-linear.

Comment: By the definition you give, yes.  I'm going by the definition of "nonlinear" for differential equations and dynamic systems, though, and sometimes terminology can vary from discipline to discipline.  I think this'll adhere to the standard, though.

Answer (score 0):

lets look at those two examples:

$$\dot\phi+\sin(\phi)=\omega$$

the solution

[image]

this is non uniform oscillator and also non linear oscillator

and
$$\dot\phi=\omega$$

the solution $~\phi(t)=\omega\,t$

[image]